# Wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError) at fastlane script

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I did add method to my [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) script:

```rb
# This is the minimum version number required.
# Update this, if you use features of a newer version
fastlane_version "2.28.2"

default_platform :ios

platform :ios do

    # some code was copied from fastlane/app_store_build_number
    def get_last_app_version(app_identifier)

        Spaceship::Tunes.login('some-user@icloud.com')
        Spaceship::Tunes.select_team

        app = Spaceship::Tunes::Application.find(app_identifier)

        train_numbers = app.all_build_train_numbers(platform: platform)
        self.order_versions(train_numbers).last
    end

    def self.order_versions(versions)
        versions.map(&:to_s).sort_by { |v| Gem::Version.new(v) }
    end

    # ....

end
```

And calls it in my fastlane action:

```rb
lane :get_ver do

    get_certificates(
        username: 'some-user@icloud.com',
        team_name: 'Our team name'
        )

    app_version = get_last_app_version('com.some-app.ios')

    # further actions
end
```

When I runs `get_ver` action, I get error `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` and can't understand what's wrong

Method defined with one argument and calling has one argument too, what a reason?

Also I did try to add argument name:

```rb
get_last_app_version(app_identifier: 'com.some-app.ios')
```

remove brackets:

```rb
get_last_app_version 'com.some-app.ios'
```

But result is same

Full error output:

```
Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:112:in `platform': [!] wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
        from Fastfile:22:in `get_last_app_version'
        from Fastfile:58:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:56:in `cruise_lane'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:74:in `run!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:333:in `run'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:108:in `take_off'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.99.0/bin/fastlane:20:in `'
        from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in `'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message says that you should pass argument to `platform` method call, which happens in this line:

```
train_numbers = app.all_build_train_numbers(platform: platform)
```

Comment: I updated code in question - now you can look that `platform` is defined. It contains in default `fastlane` script and I did not change it. Also error message does not contain anything about `all_build_train_numbers`.

Comment: Hm... Strange but when I set `platform` value directly (`app.all_build_train_numbers(platform: :ios)`) script start working. Thanks, I will go to further learn fastlane.

Comment: It's not 'defined', it's called with `:ios` argument. This doesn't mean you can refer its 'value' (whatever it is) by using `platform` call.